# Optgroups are closed after 1 item. Dynamic list

Tags: php, html

I have a select form object in index.php. The items are gotten from mySQL. What im trying is to achieve is: Create an optgroup whenever catID = NULL. In this case Section1 and Section2 should be optgroups. But the optgroups are closed after 1 option. Any tips? screenshot:

[image]

database->table:

```
catId catName
NULL --Section1--
1010 Bilar
1020 Bildelar & tillbehör
1030 Motorcycklar
1040 Motorcycklar delar & tillbehör
1050 Moped
1070 Lastbil & Truck
NULL --Section2--
2010 Bygg och Trädgår
2020 Möbler & Heminredning
2030 Husgeråd & Vitvaror
2040 Verktyg
```

HTML:

```
      <?php $count = 0; ?>
      <?php foreach($categories as $category ): $count++;?>

                 <?php if($category['catId']==NULL){?>

                    <optgroup label="<?php $category['catName']?>">

                 <?php } else{ ?>

                    <option value="<?php echo $category['catId'];?>"><?php echo $category['catName'];?></option>
                    <?php
                    $temp = $categories[($count+1)];
                     if($temp['catId']==NULL)?>
                            </optgroup>
                 <?php } ?>

             <?php endforeach;?>

        </select>
```

Comment: Inspect the contents of your $categories variable to confirm it contains what it is supposed to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  <?php $first_opt = TRUE; ?>

  <?php foreach($categories as $category ): ?>

             <?php if($category['catId']==NULL){?>

                <?php if($first_opt):?>
                    <optgroup label="<?php echo $category['catName']?>">
                    <?php $first_opt = FALSE;?>
                <?else:?>
                    </optgroup><optgroup label="<?php echo $category['catName']?>">                  
                <?endif;?>

             <?php } else{ ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $category['catId'];?>"><?php echo $category['catName'];?></option>

             <?php } ?>

         <?php endforeach;?>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```